# How can I connect to a windows computer like window remote desktop app in windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

On my windows machine I am using the window remote desktop app to connect to a remote computer. I cant find any similar apps on ubuntu to make this possible. What is your prefered choice?

Comment: VNC is ok and will do the job! Are you connecting a windows system from Ubuntu?

Comment: The same way? Ubuntu has Remmina installed by default. But teamviewer works too. Or Rdesktop. Or VNC. We also support being the server side (so the one connected to).